# Phantom Wallet - $USD Value Not Showing At Times

Tags: wallet, phantom, error, phantom-wallet

I launched a project on March 6.  After a bit of expected time, $USD values began appearing in our development/marketing wallets...as well as for the community.

As of today, some wallets are showing $USD value, and others are not.  Does anyone know why this may be?

We are Updated/Verified on Dexscreener, DEXTools, and recently BirdEye. Our Liquidity is 100% Locked/Burned

Thanks so much for the help that anyone can provide!

Respectfully,

J

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this stackexchange is not for wallet support